# Attached Property of type ObservableCollection bound to ViewModel always returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to bind an `ObservableCollection` on my `Window` to my `ViewModel` using an `Attached Property`. The binding seems to work since the `PropertyChangedCallBack` is invoked, but if I call the `GetMyProperty` method, it always returns `null`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="AttachedOberservableCollectionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AttachedOberservableCollectionTest"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <local:MainWindow.MyProperty>
            <Binding Path="MyCollection" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        </local:MainWindow.MyProperty>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace AttachedOberservableCollectionTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<int> GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<int>)obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
        }

        public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<int> value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, MyPopertyChanged));

        private static void MyPopertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newCollection = (ObservableCollection<int>)e.NewValue;
            Console.WriteLine($"New collection has {newCollection.Count} values");
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collection = GetMyProperty(this);

            if (collection == null)
                Console.WriteLine("Attached property is null");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Attached poperty has {collection.Count} values");
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AttachedOberservableCollectionTest
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> MyCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyCollection.Add(1);
            MyCollection.Add(2);
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I get:

```
New collection has 2 values
Attached property is null
```

The xaml editor in visual studio also gives the tooltip message `The value "System.Windows.Data.Binding" is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value`.

Comment: Your ViewModel does not seem to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It needs to implement it in order to let the Bindind work

Comment: That is actually not neccesary for an ObservableCollection, as long as you don't change properties on the objects it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally unclear why you are using an attached property, instead of a regular dependency property in the MainWindow class.

However, your XAML sets the attached property on the top level Grid, not the Window object:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MainWindow.MyProperty>
        <Binding Path="MyCollection" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </local:MainWindow.MyProperty>
</Grid>
```

which should actually look like

```
<Grid local:MainWindow.MyProperty="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Grid>
```

Move the assignment to the Window instance, like

```
<Window ...
    local:MainWindow.MyProperty="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

or retrieve the property value from the Grid.

---

The attached property should actually be a regular dependency property. Bind to it in the MainWindow's XAML like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
            <Setter Property="MyProperty"
                    Value="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. The reason I'm using an attached property is because I just can't figure out how to do exactly this with a dependency property (binding it directly to the viewmodel).

Comment: You mean you can't write `MyProperty="{Binding ...}"` directly in the MainWindow's XAML? See the edited answer.

Comment: I didn't know that I needed to use the Window.Style for that, your example made it clear. Thank you, I'm using a normal dependency property now.